# AS3 iOS Place a Call Issue

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, mobile

I'm currently trying to set-up a button that, when activated, will take a number from the app and call it.

I'm currently using the following code with no results;

```
var number3:String = "tel:1234567890";
var targetURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(number3);

...
function Call3 (e:MouseEvent):void {
navigateToURL(targetURL);
}
```

The Call3 function is triggered by an event listener.

When I test this however, nothing happens.

I've spent some time looking for information on placing call with an iOS device using AS3 but to no avail.

Comment: Can you throw a `trace` statement in the MouseEvent handler and see if it ever gets called?

Comment: I've put a trace in and can confirm it gets called and opens the correct URL on the computer. I only have the issue on the actual device.

Answer (score 0):

The URL scheme for making calls is `tel://`

That's probably why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Pier is correct.

Here's how the full code would look if you have a button on your stage called, **call_btn**

```
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var myNumber:Number = 5555555555;
var callString:String = "tel://"+String(myNumber);
var callURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(callString);

call_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, callNumber);
function callNumber(e:MouseEvent):void{
navigateToURL(callURL);
}
```